# list names in folder, do action and go back to folder in batch

Tags: batch-file, dos

Im facing the following:

I have a Folder with many folders named `P_1400` to `P1_1499` (A HUNDRED FOLDERS)

I want to script something that would access each folder and perform action

Lets say:

```
>cd Folder 1 
>echo hello in file.txt

>cd ..

>cd folder 2
>echo hello in file.txt

>cd ..
```

etc.. till theres no nore folders

little constriant is that some folder are missed lets say `P_1450` is missing
and some folder are named `P_1420_1` or `P_1420_2`

tHANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP FOR` and `HELP PUSHD` and then try this

```
FOR /D %%a IN (P_*) DO (
   PUSHD %%a
   echo Do some action in %%a
   POPD %%a
)
```

Comment: the action i want to execute is a for string, does a for can include a for?

Comment: yes, you can include whatever commands you need to perform in the DO block. If you like it, upvote and accept.